# LibGDX и камера телефона

Tags: libgdx, камера

Нужно получать изображение с камеры девайса, проект в LibGDX.
Пользовался вот этим https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Integrating-libgdx-and-the-device-camera. Куча устаревших классов, некоторых нет вообще. Поделитесь кто чем может)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, самое простое решение - это получение изображения с камеры на android backend. Далее выводить его на view, либо передавать bitmap через platform specific code. На android можно получить через camera api, camera2 api, openCV, и т.д.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8H75oJD0I0g